# Split string and store in data frame

Tags: r, string, dataframe, split

I have a character array, as follows .

```
char[1:3] .   
 [1] "ByShubham SharmaTOP 500 REVIEWERon 12 November 2017"   
 [2] "ByJitender Bhatiaon 16 November 2017"                
 [3] "ByMridul K.on 15 August 2017"
```

I would like the output as

```
Name Badge Date
---------------
Shubham Sharma . TOP 500 REVIEWER   12 November 2017  
Jitender Bhatia   NA                16 November 2017                
Mridul K15        NA .              August 2017
```

Comment: Is this your whole data? If not, is there any discernible structure in your strings which could be evaluated using regular expression?

Comment: @LAP yes this is my whole data. As mentioned in the question there is a possibility of only two types of string (see 1 and 2 in character list ). The issue which I'm facing is that of separation of strings as the words to be separated are concatenated without any space (for instance By, TOP, on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that:

- the input is as in the Note at the end
- the `By` at the beginning of each line is to be removed
- the input always ends in: digits month digits
- a lower case letter immediately followed by an upper case letter is to be split into two fields at that point
- `on` immediately preceded by a non-lower case character should be removed
- there are no semicolons

We insert semicolons separating the fields and remove the `By` and `on` and finally read it in using `read.table` with semicolon separator.

```
ss0 <- sub("By(.*) (\\d+ \\S+ \\d{4})$", "\\1;\\2", s)  # insert ; before date
ss1 <- sub("([^a-z])on", "\\1 ", ss0)   # remove 'on' if not after lower
ss2 <- sub("^(.*[a-z])([A-Z].*)", "\\1;\\2", ss1) # insert ; between lower & upper
ss3 <- sub("^([^;]*);([^;]*)$", "\\1;NA;\\2", ss2) # ; to ;NA; if only 2 fields
read.table(text = ss3, sep = ";", as.is = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE,
  col.names = c("Name", "Badge", "Date"))
```

giving:

```
               Name            Badge             Date
1    Shubham Sharma TOP 500 REVIEWER 12 November 2017
2 Jitender Bhatiaon             <NA> 16 November 2017
3         Mridul K.             <NA>   15 August 2017
```

This works with the example code but you may have to revise it based on the entire rules for your whole data set.

Another possibility if the input is short is to manually edit the input removing the `By` and `on` and appropriately inserting semicolons between the fields.  Then use the `read.table` statement above.

#### Note

```
s <- c( "ByShubham SharmaTOP 500 REVIEWERon 12 November 2017",
"ByJitender Bhatiaon 16 November 2017",
"ByMridul K.on 15 August 2017")
```

**Update:** (1) Modified rules slightly and code accordingly.  (2) Simplify.

Comment: Thanks @Grothendieck. That was a great help.

Answer (score 1):

With only three rows, I'd rather write the dataframe from scratch:

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("Shubham Sharma", "Jitender Bhatia", "Mridul K."),
                 Badge = c("TOP 500 REVIEWER", NA, NA),
                 Date = c(as.Date("2017-11-12"), as.Date("2017-11-16"), as.Date("2017-08-15")),
                 stringsAsFactors = F))

> df
             Name            Badge       Date
1  Shubham Sharma TOP 500 REVIEWER 2017-11-12
2 Jitender Bhatia             <NA> 2017-11-16
3       Mridul K.             <NA> 2017-08-15
```